# error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant

Tags: python, c

I am getting an error on a specific line that mimics the usage in another file.

```
PyObject *pyCharGetHeight(PyChar *self, void *closure) {
  CHAR_DATA *ch = PyChar_AsChar((PyObject *)self);
  PyObject *height = NULL;
  if(ch != NULL) height = Py_BuildValue("s", charGetHeight(ch));
  return height;
}

PyChar_addGetSetter("height", pyCharGetHeight, NULL, "Returns character's height");
```

is returning the following error, PyChar_addGetSetter... line

> error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before string constant

I am using the following includes:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "../scripts/pychar.h"
```

And pychar.h does define PyChar_addGetSetter() as prototyped here:

```
void PyChar_addGetSetter(const char *name, void *g, void *s, const char *doc);
```

The function is written in *../scripts/pychar.c* as follows:

```
void PyChar_addGetSetter(const char *name, void *g, void *s, const char *doc) {
  // make sure our list of get/setters is created
  if(pychar_getsetters == NULL) pychar_getsetters = newList();

  // make the GetSetter def
  PyGetSetDef *def = calloc(1, sizeof(PyGetSetDef));
  def->name        = strdup(name);
  def->get         = (getter)g;
  def->set         = (setter)s;
  def->doc         = (doc ? strdup(doc) : NULL);
  def->closure     = NULL;
  listPut(pychar_getsetters, def);
}
```

It seems like a structure or type is not being recognized, I am guessing my function.

Comment: `PyChar_addGetSetter` is not a function from the C API, so… where is it from? If it's a function you wrote yourself (presumably in that `"../scripts/pychar.h"` file?), you'll have to show us the source code for that function, not just the calling code and the prototype. (For example, the bug could easily be that `CHAR_DATA` is a macro with a stray paren or something.)

Comment: @abarnert The error is not coming up in the pychar.c file, and only occur is the line `PyChar_addGetSetter("height", pyCharGetHeight, NULL, "Returns character's height");` is included, this is used elsewhere without error. Most notably within pychar.c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to call a function at the top level of a .c file. You can't do that.

The error message could be a little nicer, but it looks like gcc is interpreting this as an attempt to declare a type named `PyChar_addGetSetter` and/or to declare a global variable of that type, and failing to interpret it either way, and telling you why that attempt failde.

Comment: At the top level? Can you be clearer with the first line of your answer? It does look like it's seeing it as an attempt to declare a type, but it should be declared in the header.

Comment: @ToothlessRebel: Do you still need me to clarify the first sentence?

Comment: No, I briefly confused declare and call in a moment of frustrated stupidity. I see what you meant and you were absolutely correct.