# error: expected declaration specifiers or '…' before string constant

Tags: c

Does anybody know what is wrong with this piece of code? i can't see to find the issue among the comparable questions.

The code is written in C, and i keep getting this error. I do add `-D SET_MIN_TEMP=5 -D Set_MAX_TEMP=30` to the gcc compile line to make sure the ifndefs should be false...

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifndef RUN_AVG_LENGTH
    #define RUN_AVG_LENGTH 5
#endif

#ifndef SET_MIN_TEMP
    printf("please set SET_MIN_TEMP \n");
#endif

#ifndef SET_MAX_TEMP
    printf("please set SET_MAX_TEMP \n");
#endif

typedef uint16_t sensor_id_t;
typedef uint16_t room_id_t;
typedef double sensor_value_t;
typedef time_t sensor_ts_t;     // UTC timestamp as returned by time() - notice that the size of time_t is different on 32/64 bit machine

typedef struct {
  sensor_id_t id;
  sensor_value_t value;
  sensor_ts_t ts;
} sensor_data_t;

typedef struct {
    sensor_id_t sensor_id;
    room_id_t room_id;
    double running_avg[5];
    sensor_ts_t timestamp;
} sensor_node_t;


#endif // CONFIG_H
```

Comment: `Set_MAX_TEMP` != `SET_MAX_TEMP` because C is case-sensitive.

Comment: Which line are you getting an error for? Why do you have `printf()` lines at top-level like this?

Comment: If you want to cause compile-time errors when a macro isn't defined use `#error`.

Comment: damnit how did i miss that one -.-, thank you bro

Comment: well i was using #warning before, but changed it because i kept getting an error, now i know why as well...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371206/error-expected-declaration-specifiers-or-before-string-constant)

Answer (score 18):

You can not use a function call (`printf`) outside a function.  You should take a look at `#error` if you want to report errors at compilation...

See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Diagnostics.html)

Comment: The `#ifndef` is supposed to hide those calls and prevent the error.

Comment: Yes, but it seems like that the OP passed the wrong arguments (case), so the wrong `printf` statements will remain...

Comment: I think that's the point -- he was really wondering why the `#ifndef` wasn't working. And it turned out to be a simple typo.

Comment: I also think that, but nevertheless the `printf` is wrong and should be replaced...

Comment: I agree with that, which is why I wrote it in a comment 15 minutes ago.