# error trying to #include headerfile within main function

Tags: c, ide

Newbie question: To my knowledge the way `#include` works is that it copy-pastes whatever is inside the included file to the designated spot. All I want is to `#include` a file which only holds a `printf()`.

And while this works perfectly in any online IDE I have tried, in **Code::Blocks** I receive

> error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant

This is the **main** file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    #include "null.h"
}
```

And this is the included **null.h**:

```
printf("Hello, world\n");
```

I have tried `#include <stdio.h>` above `printf()` function call as well as calling the file null.c however nothing seems to work. I have searched Google but can't wrap my head around what this error has to do with any of the explanations provided.

edit: I now use gcc via cmd in order to compile which works for me.

Comment: You code seems to be running fine for me. Even `gcc -E file.c` gives expected output.

Comment: Thank you. What IDE/compiler are you using (if you don't mind me asking)?

Comment: I'm using gcc `10.2.1` on Fedora 33

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: expected declaration specifiers or '…' before string constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606697/error-expected-declaration-specifiers-or-before-string-constant)

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will try again with a Linux VM. I have seen this particular page, Krishna but it does not help me solve my problem.

Comment: I have a more deep question. Is this a good practice to include (or conditionally include) code inside a function? Even though it works fine from a preprocessor perspective?