# The .ccp and .h / header files output error 'this declaration has no storage class or type specifier' with implementation of SendInput function

Tags: c++, storage-class-specifier

So my problem is I keep getting error

"this declaration has no storage class or type specifier"

"the size of an array must be greater than zero"

" expected a ';' "

I don't know what's wrong. I tried to look online and find no specific solution to my problem other than generic solutions like defining the class for the terms in my .h file but I don't even know where to begin defining 'ZeroMemory' or something like that. You can see in my code, in my Source.cpp, I have commented out the code and did a paste crossover into my .h file. The error presented above appears and it seems it won't compile but its fine compiling if I leave them in my Source.cpp file instead. How do I go about solving this? I'm at my wits end here.

BTW I want them on a separate file which is a .h file.

Source.cpp file

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Input Buttons.h" 


int main()
{
    //INPUT blocks[6], grabs[4];

    
    /*ZeroMemory(blocks, sizeof(blocks));*/
    /*ZeroMemory(grabs, sizeof(grabs));*/

    //virutal key list website
    //learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes


    //Setting up key/mouse input environment

    //a
    //blocks[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    //blocks[0].ki.wVk = 0x41; //keyboard button 'a'
    //blocks[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY; //press down

    //blocks[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    //blocks[1].ki.wVk = 0x41;
    //blocks[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; //let go



    //d
    //blocks[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    //blocks[2].ki.wVk = 0x44; //keyboard button 'd'
    //blocks[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;

    //blocks[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    //blocks[3].ki.wVk = 0x44;
    //blocks[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;



    //s
    //blocks[4].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    //blocks[4].ki.wVk = 0x53; //keyboard button 's'
    //blocks[4].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;

    //blocks[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    //blocks[5].ki.wVk = 0x53;
    //blocks[5].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;



    //i
    //grabs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    //grabs[0].ki.wVk = 0x49; //keyboard button 'i'
    //grabs[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;

    //grabs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    //grabs[1].ki.wVk = 0x49;
    //grabs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;



    //k
    //grabs[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    //grabs[2].ki.wVk = 0x4B; //keyboard button 'k'
    //grabs[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;

    //grabs[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    //grabs[3].ki.wVk = 0x4B;
    //grabs[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

}
```

Input Buttons.h

```
#pragma once

using namespace std;

INPUT blocks[6], grabs[4];

ZeroMemory(blocks, sizeof(blocks));
ZeroMemory(grabs, sizeof(grabs));


//a
blocks[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
blocks[0].ki.wVk = 0x41; //keyboard button 'a'
blocks[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY; //press down

blocks[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
blocks[1].ki.wVk = 0x41;
blocks[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; //let go
```

[Error in image form from my perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpi5k.png)

Comment: Do you know what a *function* is? Because everything below the `INPUT blocks[6], grabs[4];` line in your header belongs in a function, and as a matter of course, *not* in a header file unless inlined. I suggest a good book on C++. If you want to gut `main` (coincidentally, a function, albeit a special one), and relocate that code to a different function, so be it, but what you're doing ain't that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371206/error-expected-declaration-specifiers-or-before-string-constant)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it currently is, your header file has "freestanding" execution code.
This is not possible in C++ - C++ is not a scripting language where you can execute code in arbitrary files.

Every executable code needs to be in a function.
So you better declare a function prototype in your `Buttons.h` with the necessary data types.

Then you create a function in `Buttons.cpp` where you *define* the function with the code you want to execute and compile and link it. You can then include `Buttons.h` and call the function from `main()`

Buttons.h

```
#include <conio.h>

void do_stuff();
```

Buttons.cpp

```
void do_stuff() {
    INPUT blocks[6];
    INPUT grabs[4];
    //... rest of your code//
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "Buttons.h" // makes do_stuff() visible in Source.cpp

int main() {
    do_stuff();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually solved it. Just created 'Buttons.h' and put it into a struct. However I put the 'INPUT' details within the first layer of the struct and then I created a function called 'do_stuff()' and put in the details of the 'INPUT' names inside of the 'do_stuff()' function. Now the problem is, how do I implement 'SendInput'? Cuz now it doesn't work cuz I don't know what to put into the first parameter. I tried 'SendInput(1, playerButtons.grabs, sizeof(INPUT)) and there was no buttons pressed at all. Can you help me on that?